# Incompressible surfaces in surface bundles of $S^1$ that are homologous to the fiber are homotopic to the fiber?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I was reading Thurston's "A norm for the homology of 3-manifolds" and I had some questions that I think are pretty basic but have me stumped at the moment.  Let $M^3$ be a compact 3-manifold that fibers over $S^1$ and let $\Sigma$ be the fiber.  Let $\Sigma'$ be an incompressible surface in $M^3$ that is in the same homology class as the fiber $\Sigma$.

After introducing his norm, Thurston goes on to prove that $\Sigma'$ is isotopic to $\Sigma$ in section 3 of the above paper.  At the beginning of this section, Thurston gives a brief argument for why $\Sigma'$ must be homotopic to $\Sigma$.  This homotopic part is the part that I do not understand and I wanted to ask about.

The first thing Thurston asks us to do is to look at the covering induced by projection to $S^1$  which is homeomorphic to $\Sigma \times \mathbb{R}$.  Apparently, $\Sigma'$ lifts to this cover (this is presumably because of the condition that it is homologous to the fiber but I do not understand why this is) and then composing this lift with the projection $\Sigma \times \mathbb{R} \to \Sigma$, we have a map $\Sigma' \to \Sigma$.

Now apparently this map is degree 1, although it is not clear to me why.  Then Thurston says that since $\Sigma \to \Sigma'$ is a degree 1 map that is $\pi_1$-injective, it is homotopic to a homeomorphism (which is intuitively believable although I would not know how to prove it).  Then lifting that homotopy to $\Sigma \times \mathbb{R}$ and projecting it to $M$ gives the desired result.

Just to summarize my questions:

(1) Why does $\Sigma'$ lift?

(2) Why is the lift composed with the projection degree 1?

(3) Why is the degree 1, $\pi_1$-injective map $\Sigma' \to \Sigma$ homotopic to a homeomorphism?

Comment: Hint for (1): Consider the element $a\in H^1(M)$ which is Poincare-dual to your 2nd homology class $c$. Then  $a$ defines a homomorphism $\phi: \pi_1(M)\to H_1(M)\to Z$. Show that if $\Sigma$ is a surface in $M$ (incompressible or not) representing $c$ then the image of $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ in $\pi_1(M)$ lies in the kernel of $\phi$. Now, use the covering theory.